# Finding confidence intervals via Chi-square test

Tags: statistics

I have several samples (they are variances). I have to compute their (i) mean value (easy), and their confidence interval (via Chi-squared test).

I work in Matlab environment, but I would like rewrite the functions, so to have a full control of each step.

The question is: how is the formula to compute the lower (`low`) and the upper (`up`) value for passing to `errorbar(x, y_variance, low, up)`?

Thank you and bye,
Giacomo

**EDIT**

I try to start.

Suppose we have a set of $n$ samples $x_i$, were $\sigma^2$ their variance.

At this point I know that:

$L = \frac{(n-1)\sigma^2}{\chi^2_\frac{\alpha}{2}}$,

and

$U = \frac{(n-1)\sigma^2}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$.

But, at this point, I do not know how to compute $\chi^2_\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$, where $\alpha$ is the level of significance.

**SECOND EDIT**

In Matlab environment, is very easy find $\chi^2_\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$.

The code is this:

```
for i = 1:100
  C(i,:) = chi2inv(1-[0.995 0.99 0.975 0.95 0.9 0.1 0.05 0.025 0.01 0.005], i);
end
```

So, e.g., $\chi^2_{0.975}=C(n-1,3)$, 3, because 3 is the column of 0.975.

But my question remains: there is a way to compute directly these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\chi^2$ distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom has the
cumulative distribution function

$$F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{t^{r/2-1} e^{-t/2}}{2^{r/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}dt.$$

The values you are trying to compute are the solutions for $x$
in $F(x) = \frac\alpha2$ and $F(x) = 1 - \frac\alpha2$.

I'm not aware of a closed form for solving those equations.
You could use numeric methods to solve for $x$.
One thought is, either integrate upward from zero or downward from infinity until
the terms in your sum exceed $\frac\alpha2,$ then interpolate the last step
so the sum is exactly $\frac\alpha2.$
It is important to have a good way to compute the integration steps, however;
doing this while reliably giving as accurate a result as Matlab's `chi2inv`
will be a difficult task, I think.

Comment: Thank you. I know that `chi2inv` solve my problem, but I was curios to see the formula.